# Example of calculating conditional probabilities

Tags: probability

We fill a bag with three fruits. Every fruit we put in the bag has the same chance to be an apple, a banana, or a pear. One randomly pulls a fruit out of the bag, it's an apple. What is the probability that the others two fruits in the bag to be apples as well?

I would say that we don't care about the result of the first draw and the probability that the other two are apples is $(\frac 13)^2$

Comment: That is correct if you assume the three fruit are independent and exchangeable and the draw does not depend on the fruit type.  It does not matter which of the three you take out, so you may as well assume it was the third and calculate the probability of the first two being apples.  In fact you do not even need to put the third fruit in - just look at it if you want, though you not even have to do that.

Comment: You may be worried about the relation to the [boy-girl problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boy_or_Girl_paradox).  Such concern is unfounded as in the boy-girl problem we are told *at least one of (but not which of)* the children is a girl.  Here, we are told very specifically that the fruit we happen to draw (*which is enough to distinguish it from the other fruits*) was an apple.  Compare this to the boy-girl problem where we ring the doorbell and a girl happens to answer the door (*assuming each child would have been equally likely to answer the door*) or being told the eldest is a girl.

Comment: @ JMoravitz  you understand my worry

Comment: You have to be careful with conditional probabilities. I get $\frac{1}{19}$.

Comment: @ John Douma Can you give your answer, please

Comment: Use Bayes' theorem and compute the probability of getting three apples given that there is at least one.

Comment: John Douma You tell me to be careful and JMoravitz tell me there is nothing to worry about. who am I going to believe?

Comment: Mathematics isn't faith based. You must compute the answer. One way to see that it is what I say it is is to write the $27$ ways to have three pieces of fruit in the bag. There will only be one way to get three apples. How many ways are there to have at least one apple in the bag? Your original solution would be correct if you were filling the bag and pulled an apple on the first draw. Then there would be a $\frac{1}{9}$ chance of pulling an apple on each of the next two draws. This problem is different because when you pull the apple from the bag, you only know it was put there on some draw.

Comment: @JohnDouma You are getting the correct answer *to the wrong problem*.  This is not a question of "*given that there is at least one apple in the bag what is the probability that the other two fruit are also apples*"  It is the question of "*given that* **the first** *fruit drawn is an apple, what is the probability that the other two fruit are also apples*"  Those are completely different questions.  It is this second question we are trying to answer.

Comment: @JohnDouma The first fruit being **put** in the bag being an apple and asking if the remaining two are also apples is equivalent to the first fruit being **pulled** from the bag being an apple and asking if the remaining two are apples because we can assume [*without loss of generality*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Without_loss_of_generality) that the fruit are pulled in the same order they were put in.

Comment: If everyone understands the question differently, I am not very advanced in answering the question.

Comment: @JMoravitz The problem says an apple was pulled from the bag. What if there was only one apple? How do you know it wasn't the second piece of fruit placed in the bag?

Comment: @JohnDouma it might have been.  It is **without loss of generality** that we could have assumed it was the first.  If we were to condition on it actually being the first fruit that was drawn and if we were to repeat the argument for if it was in fact the second fruit that was drawn and condition on that, etc... we find that the unmentioned cases of it being second or third fruit that was drawn is symmetrical to the first for a total probability of $\frac{1}{27}+\frac{1}{27}+\frac{1}{27}=\frac{1}{9}$ as expected.

Comment: @JMoravitz I do see what you mean. Even though, there is only one possible bag of fruit with three apples, there are multiple ways to observe it. I apologize for the confusion. Cerise, please accept the answer of $\frac{1}{9}$. He is correct. My answer was answering the probability of getting three apples given at least one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The three fruit are placed into the bag and then one of the three is randomly pulled out.

We may assume without loss of generality that the first fruit placed in the bag was indeed the same fruit as what was pulled out.  We are told that the fruit pulled out was an apple.  This leaves just the question of what the second and third fruit were.  They were each independently an apple with probability $\frac{1}{3}$ for a final probability of $$\frac{1}{9}$$

If this is unconvincing, go ahead and explicitly refer to all $3^4=81$ possible events, keeping track of not only the outcome of the first fruit but also which of the fruits was the one randomly selected and approach directly with definition of conditional probability.

You will find that of these $81$ equally likely different possible events, $3\times 1\times 3\times 3$ correspond to the fruit being drawn being an apple (*pick which numbered fruit was the one that was drawn (3 options) set it as an apple (1 option) and pick the type of fruit for each of the remaining (9 options)*).  Of these, $3\times 1\times 1\times 1$ correspond to all fruit being apples.  This gives a probability of:

$$\frac{3\times 1\times 1\times 1}{3\times 1\times 3\times 3} = \frac{1}{9}$$

---

The wording of the question is important.  What we are conditioning on is not the event that there is at least one apple in the bag... what we are conditioning on is that when randomly pulling a single fruit from the bag that it was an apple.  The exact text from the OP is "**One randomly pulls a fruit out of the bag, it's an apple.**"  This is different than "*Timmy only likes to eat apples and so he searches the bag for an apple and intentionally pulls one out.*"  In our actual problem, there was a chance to fail to have procured an apple even in the scenario that there were apples available.  Timmy searching the bag there is no chance to fail to procure an apple except in the scenario that there were no apples in the bag at all.

Compare this to the [Boy-Girl Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boy_or_Girl_paradox) and very specifically to the [First Question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boy_or_Girl_paradox#First_question) in the boy-girl problem where we are told that the *eldest* child is a girl.

Compare this to the boy-girl problem where *a girl answers the door when the doorbell is rung* but we don't know whether it was the elder or the younger child.  Here, even though we don't have a way of knowing the child's relative age... *we are still able to distinguish her from her sibling by the very fact that it was she and not her sibling who answered the door*.  This is the same scenario as we are in here with this problem.  The fruit we *happened to have pulled* was an apple.  We did not seek out an apple intentionally.

This is a different question than the [Second Question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boy_or_Girl_paradox#Second_question) where we are told at least one of the children are girls but not which and are given no information or way to distinguish which.

Answer (score 1):

I apologize to both @JMoravitz and @Cerice for causing confusion. I originally had an answer of $\frac{1}{19}$ because I reckoned that there were $27$ possible bags of fruit and only $8$ of them don't have an apple which leaves $19$ possible bags of fruit of which only one contains three apples.

This reasoning is incorrect because although there is only one possible bag of fruit with three apples there are three possible ways to observe it. The apple pulled from the bag could have been the first, second or third apple from the bag with three apples.

If the apple drawn was the first fruit placed then there are $3\times 3=9$ choices for the other two.

Likewise, if the apple drawn was the second fruit placed there are $9$ choices for the other two and if the apple drawn was the third fruit placed there are $9$ choices so there are $27$ possible ways to observe a single apple selected at random and $3$ of these contain all apples. Therefore, the probability of observing two more apples is $\frac{3}{27}=\frac{1}{9}$.

I only posted this to clarify any confusion that I may have caused. Please accept JMoravitz's answer since he suffered from no such malady.